# werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'auth.login'. Did you mean 'auth.register' instead?

Tags: python, flask

Trato de crear un formulario de registro e inicio de sesión básico, pero recibo el siguiente error:

> werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'auth.login'. Did you mean 'auth.register' instead?

Soy nuevo en Python/Flask, intenté revisando toda la documentación pero no tuve suerte

¿Me podríais ayudar?

**Código `__init__.py`**

```py
import os

from flask import Flask 

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='mikey',
        DATABASE_HOST=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_HOST'),
        DATABASE_PASSWORD=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        DATABASE_USER=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_USER'),
        DATABASE=os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE'),
    )                          

    from . import bd

    bd.init_app(app)

    from . import auth

    app.register_blueprint(auth.bp)
```

**Código `auth.py`**

```py
import functools 

from flask import(
    Blueprint, flash, g, render_template, request, redirect, url_for , session
)
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

from todo.bd import get_bd

bp = Blueprint('auth', __name__, url_prefix='/auth')

@bp.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    if request.method =='POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        bd, c = get_bd()
        error = None
        c.execute (
            'select id from user where username = %s'
        )
        if not username:
            error='Username es requerido'
        if not password:
            error='Password es requerido'

         elif c.fetchone() is not None:
             error ='Usuario {} se encuentra registrado'.format(username)

         if error is None:
             c.execute(
                  'insert into user (username,password) values (%s, %s)',
                  (username,generate_password_hash(password))
             )
             bd.commit()

             return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

    flash(error)

    return render_template('auth/register.html')
        
bp.route('/login', methods=['POST','GET'])
def login():
    if request.method =='POST':
        username=request.form['username']
        password=request.form['password']
        bd, c = get_bd()
        error= None
        c.execute (
            'select * from user where username = %s' , (username,)
        )
        user= c.fetchone()

        if user is  None:
            error = 'Usuario y/o contraseña invalida'
        elif not check_password_hash(user['password'], password):
            error = 'Usuario y/o contraseña invalida'

        if error is None:
            session.clear()
            session['user_id'] = user ['id']
            return redirect(url_for('index.html'))

    flash(error)
    return render_template('auth/login.html')
```

**Código  base html**

```html
<!doctype html>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - Todo List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='style.css') }}">
    <nav>
        <h1>Todo List</h1>
        <ul>
            {% if g.user %}
                <li><span>{{g.user['username']}}</span></li>
                <li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.logout') }}" > cerrar session</li>
            {% else %}
                <li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.register') }}" > registrarse </li>
                <li><a href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}"> iniciar sesiona </li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section class="content">
        <header>
            {% block header%}{ endblock%} 
        </header>
        {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
            <div class="flash">{{message}}</div>
        {% endfor %}

        {% endblock %} 
    </section>
```

**Código  register html**

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block header %}
    <h1><title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block content%}
    <form method="post">
        <label for="username"Username></label>
        <input name="username" id="username" required/>
        <label for="password"Password></label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required/>
        <input type="submit" name="Registrarse"/>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**Código login html**

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block header %}
    <h1><title>{% block title %}Iniciae sesiòn{% endblock %}</title></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block contenet %}
    <form method="post">
        <label for="username"Username></label>
        <input name="username" id="username" required/>
        <label for="password"Password></label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required/>
        <input type="submit" name="Iniciar sesiòn"/>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tu error está en auth.py, cuando tras registrar a un usuario retornas esto:

```
return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
```

Y si leí bien tu código entonces auth no tiene una extensión login.

```
return redirect(url_for('auth/login'))
```

Comment: Gracias revise el código y auth no tiene una extensión login 
           bp.route('/login', methods=['POST','GET']) @bp.route('/login', methods=['POST','GET'])

Comment: Si te sirvio mi solución puedes marcarla como correcta, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione, prueba pegando la siguiente linea en el **init**.py al final antes del return app.

app.add_url_rule("/", endpoint="index")

La razón por la que no se logra visualizar ninguna vista es porque no esta resolviendo desde la raíz.